# Get ALL tweets (Call Python tweepy.Cursor(api.search without a q parameter)

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have some Python code to get all tweets about a specific subject in a certain language:

```
tweepy.Cursor(api.search,  
              q="Giraffes",
              since="2015-10-10", 
              until="2015-10-11",
              count=100).items())
```

I want to remove the `q=` part so that I am saying get me ALL tweets from
such and such date.

I know this will return tons of tweets etc, i know that, but we can just ignore
that problem as I will be filtering on language and other things so I dont expect to get tons and tons of results.

If I remove the `q=` part I get an error.

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to return all tweets without providing a search query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449870/how-to-return-all-tweets-without-providing-a-search-query)

Answer (score 3):

When you use `api.search`, it expects a search query. To get tweets without a keyword (that is without `q=`), you may try something like:

1) `api.user_timeline` with a `screen_name=` or

2) `api.home_timeline` returns the time_line tweets of the API account.

Example:

```
tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name=USER).pages()
```

or

```
tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).pages()
```

Comment: thanks for that. what are time_line tweets? and whats the screen_name?

Comment: see http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v3.4.0/api.html#timeline-methods and the `screen_name` is the twitter @USER without the @ (e.g. for @CNN the screen_name would be CNN ).

Comment: im sorry bro, im not following, is that _really_ the best way to get all tweets regardless of user/account/anything? my end goal is to get all the french tweets from yesterday regardless of who posted them. sorry, for being so dumb, i havent really used tweepy before, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

can't help much about removing the `query` part.. try `q=""`.
But if you want tweets in a specific language, you can use  `tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="Giraffe", since = "2020-06-05", until = "2020-06-21",lang="en")` this will fetch you tweets posted in English.
I hope it helps.