# how to return all tweets without providing a search query

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am working on a text mining project that deals with analyzing tweets.

I would like to get all tweets tweeted in english during a short period of time(not more than a day), without having the result matching to a specific search query, trend, or user criteria.

I am familiar with tweepy's api.search function. However, when i try to run it without a search query:

```
api.search(count=remaining_tweets, since_id=str(since_id),lang='en', max_id=str(max_id-1))
```

i get the following message: "exception raised, waiting 15 minutes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the tweet by giving `*` to the query parameter:

```
tweets = api.search(q='*', lang='en', count=200, since_id=since_id, max_id=max_id)
```

If you need a specific number of tweets, you could use tweepy Cursor like this:

```
# Get 1000 English tweets from max_id
tweets = [tweet for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(
    api.search, q='*', lang='en', count=200, max_id=max_id).items(1000)]
```

Comment: Is it possible to get all tweets from past one min with out passing the max_id or query_string?

Comment: Does anyone know to get all tweets with APIv2? It seems that `*` is not working.